# Truncate cosmos's documentdb's collection (python)

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Here is a use case that I want to truncate cosmos collection on daily basis and repopulate the data again from some another data source.
But I am not able to find that how can I truncate any collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the MongoDB API, you can call:

```
db.coll.remove({})
```

If you're using the DocumentDB API, you would need to query for all documents and then, one by one, remove them. Something likely to be more efficient in a stored procedure.

Alternatively, for either api, you can simply delete and re-create the collection. Depending on the quantity of data you have, this might turn out to be the most efficient in both the MongoDB and DocumentDB case, and you wouldn't have to worry about continuation tokens or partition fanout.